# How is "pin code" generated with javascript

Tags: javascript

so basicly theres one game, where you have to figure out "pin code" to proceed, it is 6 digits and i have the script source, but i cant really understand how it is generated, can anyone explain how its done?

I pasted full javascript code here:
http://pastebin.com/nn9R7Nrw

I understand that this pin is verifyed with this:

```
    $('.pin').find('p').each(function(){

        pin = $(this);
        pinNumber = pin.html();

        if (pinNumber == '' && !valSet && val != ''){
            pin.html(val);
            pinVal += val;
            valSet = true;
        } else if (val == ''){
            pin.html('');
        }

        pinVal += pinNumber;

    });
```

Am i on right path if i think that user entered value is being checked with something in pin.html document or what?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the jQuery library, so check the [JQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com) for and explanation of the .html() function, and the other functions in that code block.